# Making Once API Request Per Day on my Github Pages Project

Tags: python, reactjs, frontend, github-pages

I have seen a similar post on Stack Overflow, but it was more about limiting the API calls once for each client but I am looking for a more global solution so localStorage does not help my case.

The way my app works is that I have the backend set-up in a free backend host so given the free bandwidth, it can only handle one call at a time. So, if multiple clients use the app at the same time, and since I have to make an API call to that backend for each client, it would be very slow for some.

Some logic about the backend I've set up is that what it serves for the request is the same throughout each day. So I was wondering if there is a way to get that response data from the backend each day only once for my frontend globally. For instance, how could I get that response once on each day and save it as a json file on my root frontend project so I can serve that to each client instead of making an API call for each client?

I am using github pages for my frontend and using React for the project.

Comment: maybe you make static pages with loaded data daily and host them ?

Comment: but is there a way to automate it? Because if I'm understanding you correct, your solution would have me fetch the response manually every day and update my static pages accordingly.

Comment: or maybe other way around, make a git clone of your project on server , have json file there which contain data in project, and daily make git push  there to project

Comment: oh I could actually make that. A tricky solution but would work thank you. Also how do I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: Selam Atilla. I think GitHub actions can achieve this. There's already a `on: schedule` section in the pipeline which can run the action at regular intervals. Executing git command and changing the files according to the response is the way to go.

Comment: @doneforaiur Selam Thank you very much. This was for a passion project of mine so I did not want to deal with a workaround from the backend like updating the repo there but I'm glad there is this solution. I will look into it.